# Extract the content of OUTLINE ( or AL OUTLINE ) from VS Code

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

Is there any bash command so that we can extract the content of OUTLINE or AL OUTLINE section of the VS Code and write the same into some text document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't get a better answer, you can try the [Show Functions extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qrti.funclist).

It can produce an output of a (clickable) list of functions and symbols into a separate editor which you can then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to copy and paste.

You don't say what languages you are using, I use the following for .js files:

```
"funcList": {
    "doubleSpacing": true,
    "filters": [
      {
        "extensions": [
          ".js"
        ],
        "native": "/^[a-z]+\\s+\\w+\\s*\\(.*\\)/mgi",
        "display": "/\\S* +(\\w+\\s*\\(.*\\))/1",
        "sort": 0
      }
    ]
}
```

which captures and displays the function name and args like:

```
loadCountryTaxonomy(country)

toggleSearchResultsPanel()

updatetaxArticleQueries(data)
```

but you can modify the regex to your requirements.  I don't try to list symbols other than functions but apparently you can with this extension.

Answer (score 7):

I made a VSCode extension to accomplish this.

[Extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmbeach.list-symbols)

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jmbeach/vscode-list-symbols)

Install and run `ctrl + shift + p` -> `List Symbols`

Comment: Very useful, thank you. Only thing missing is inheritance hierarchy (at least for C++).